# How to understand the Riemann surface of $\log z$ using the formal definition of Riemann surface?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I am a beginner studying Riemann surface. First things first, I learned about the definition of Riemann surface as follows.

**Definition**: A Riemann surface $X$ is defined by the following data:

1. a connected Hausdorff topological space $X$;
2. an open cover $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A}$ of $X$;
3. for each $\alpha\in A$, a homeomorphism $\phi_\alpha:U_\alpha\rightarrow V_\alpha$ to an open subset $V_\alpha\subset\mathbb{C}$ in such a way that for each $\alpha,\beta\in A$, if $U_\alpha \cap U_\beta\neq \emptyset$, the transition functions
   $$\phi_\beta\circ\phi^{-1}_\alpha:\phi_\alpha(U_\alpha\cap U_\beta)\rightarrow\phi_\beta(U_\alpha\cap U_\beta),$$
   is bi-holomorphic, namely, holomorphic with inverse holomorphic.

We know the famous Riemann surface for $\log z$, which has the following shape
[image]

How can I describe such surface with the formal definition above? In other words, I need to construct a precise $U_\alpha$, $\phi_\alpha$ and transition map to describe the Riemann surface for $\log z$, not using intuitive words such as "gluing", "rotate", "visualized like parking lot" etc...

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: treating  it as a subset defined by $e^w=z$ in $\Bbb{C}^2$, and taking $(w, z) \mapsto w$ as a single chart so be OK

Answer (score 1):

We want to show the following defines a *Riemann surface*:
$$\mathscr{M}:= \bigg\{(z,f(z))\text{ }\bigg|\text{ }z\in \mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}\text{ }\text{ and }\text{ }f(z):= Log(z)\bigg\}.$$
(Graph of principle branch of log(z))

---

**A.)** We may define a **global chart** into $\mathbb{C}$ by projecting onto the first coordinate:
$$\varphi:\mathscr{M}\to\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\};$$
$$(z,f(z))\mapsto z.$$
This is a *homeomorphism* since it has inverse:
$$\varphi^{-1}:\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}\to \mathscr{M};$$
$$z\mapsto (z,f(z))$$
and both are arguably continuous. In particular, take a convergent domain sequence: $(z_n,f(z_n))\to(z,f(z))$ and observe that:
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\varphi\big((z_n,f(z_n))\big) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}z_n = \varphi\big((\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}z_n,f(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}z_n))\big) = \varphi\big(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(z_n,f(z_n))\big) = \varphi\big((z,f(z))\big),$$
where in the second to last equality, we apply continuity of $f$. So $\varphi$ preserves limits of sequences and is thus continuous as well. Similarly, for a convergent image sequence: $z_n\to z$, we have:
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\varphi^{-1}(z_n) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(z_n,f(z_n)) = (\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}z_n,f(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}z_n)) = \varphi^{-1}(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}z_n) = \varphi^{-1}(z),$$
where in the third to last equality we used continuity of $f(z)$.
Moreover, being the only chart, the *transition maps* are:
$$\varphi\circ \varphi^{-1} = Id_{\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}}\text{ }\text{ }\text{ and }\text{ }\text{ }\varphi^{-1}\circ\varphi = Id_{\mathscr{M}},$$
which are trivially *holomorphic*. $\square$

---

**B.)** **Connectedness.** Regardless of topologies chosen, $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism, which means $\varphi^{-1}$ is continuous. So towards contradiction, if $\mathscr{M}$ was a disjoint union of *clopen*, proper subsets, the $\varphi^{-1}$-pre-images (i.e. images through $\varphi$) of the components would remain clopen. Since $\varphi$ is also injective, disjointness is preserved. This shows that $\varphi(\mathscr{M}) = \mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$ is disconnected. But it is well known to the contrary that $\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$ is connected. $\square$

---

**C.)** Lastly, we want to prove $\mathscr{M}$ is **Hausdorff**. Accordingly, let $(z,f(z))\neq (w,f(w))\in\mathscr{M}$. Then $z\neq w\in \mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$ (using contrapositive of injectivity of $\varphi$). We know $\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$ is Hausdorff, so we have the following is satisfied:
$$\exists U,V\in \tau_{\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}}: (z\in U)\wedge (w\in V)\wedge (U\cap V = \emptyset).$$
This gives us:
$$\exists \widetilde{U},\widetilde{V}\in \tau_{\mathscr{M}}: \big((z,f(z))\in \widetilde{U}\big)\wedge \big((w,f(w))\in\widetilde{V}\big)\wedge\big(\widetilde{U}\cap\widetilde{V}=\emptyset\big),$$
where $\widetilde{U} := \varphi^{-1}(U)$ and $\widetilde{V}:= \varphi^{-1}(V)$; And since $\varphi^{-1}$ is injective, it preserves disjointness. Therefore $\mathscr{M}$ is Hausdorff. $\square$
*Note: The topology on $\mathscr{M}$ is implied to be the pullback topology for which ever topology is chosen on $\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$.*

---

From $(A)$, $(B)$, and $(C)$, we may conclude that $\mathscr{M}$, given the pullback topology from its global chart, is a Riemann surface. $\blacksquare$
*My text reference is Rick Miranda's "Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces" (p.10).*

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but second-countability is necessary? I did not notice such contidion existed in my textbook.

Comment: Secondly, why is the global chart $\phi$ homeomorphism? $z$ could maps to lots of $(z,f(z))$ when $z$'s have arguments differing from $2k\pi$.

Comment: If we let $\phi$ maps $(z,f(z))$ to $\log |z|+i \text{Arg} z$, it will work, I think.

Comment: In real manifolds, the reason for the second-countability axiom is for constructions involving partitions of unity. I have not seen the same thing used in the complex case, but I assume it carries over. It is listed in Miranda's text too. I left it out above. You were right about the branches of log making $\varphi$ not 1-1, so I restricted to one branch. And edited the heck out of the post for the topological proofs. One last thing I wanted to have written is that it seems desirable to define the connected sum of all the graphs of branches as a Riemann surface.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to describe the Riemann surface of $\log z$ using the fundemental definition of Riemann surface.

First, constructing a surface $X$ with coordinate $(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,\theta)$ where $-\infty<\theta<\infty$ and $0<r<1$. Clearly,$X$ is a Hausdorff topogical space, which satisfies condition 1.

Second, constructing a bunch of open set covering $X$. For arbitrary $x_\alpha=(r_\alpha \cos\theta_\alpha,r_\alpha\sin\theta_\alpha,\theta_\alpha)\in X$, there is a isomorphism $f:\{|z-z_\alpha|<\delta\}\rightarrow U_\alpha$ where $z_\alpha = r_\alpha e^{i\theta_\alpha\pi}$ and $\delta$ is suffiently small. Therefore $U_\alpha$ is an open set, and $\{U_\alpha\}$ covers $X$.

Third, constructing $\phi_\alpha:(r \cos\theta,r\sin\theta,\theta)\in U_\alpha\rightarrow \log r+i\theta\in V_\alpha$. Clearly, $V_\alpha\subset\mathbb{C}$, and $\phi_\alpha$ is homeomorphism. And the transition function $\phi_\beta\circ\phi_\alpha^{-1}$ is just a identity function, obviously holomorphic.

Now we have proved the Riemann surface for $\log z$ satisfies all three conditions of the fundemental definition.

Is my proof correct? Thanks for your criticize.

Comment: It seems as though you mean to embed a metric ball about a point on the surface for your chart domain, $U_{\alpha}$. I would like to see this $f$ explicitly, but I think the rest of this works! And also why restrict $r$ to 1?

Comment: You are right! Restricting $r$ to 1 is useless.

Comment: What do you think about this? $log:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C}\cong\mathbb{R}^2$, so the graph would be in $\mathbb{C^2}\cong\mathbb{R}^4$. This helicoid like construction is in $\mathbb{R}^3$, how do we reconcile?